# LWC hide search result

Tags: lightning-web-components

Unable to hide the custom lookup search result on mouse click outside of search result display area. Tried with mouse out on div(lwcCustomLookup.html line 40) of searchResult div but it hiding on entering of the mouse on the search result.

The screenshot is of lookup field with results. result list should hide once the mouse clicked/out outside of result list.
[image]

lwcCustomLookupController.cls

```
public with sharing class lwcCustomLookupController {
    public lwcCustomLookupController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<SObJectResult> getResults(String ObjectName, String fieldName, String value) {
        List<SObJectResult> sObjectResultList = new List<SObJectResult>();
        system.debug(fieldName+'-------------'+ObjectName+'---++----------'+value);
        if(String.isNotEmpty(value))
            for(sObject so : Database.Query('Select Id,'+fieldName+' FROM '+ObjectName+' WHERE '+fieldName+' LIKE \'%' + value + '%\'')) {
                String fieldvalue = (String)so.get(fieldName);
                sObjectResultList.add(new SObjectResult(fieldvalue, so.Id));
            }

        return sObjectResultList;
    }

    public class SObJectResult {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String recName;
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id recId;

        public SObJectResult(String recNameTemp, Id recIdTemp) {
            recName = recNameTemp;
            recId = recIdTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

lwcCustomLookup.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            Custom Lookup in Lightning Web Components
        </h3>
        <div slot="footer">

        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">

                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div class="slds-combobox_container">

                        <div class={txtclassname} data-id="resultBox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">

                                <div>
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon iconheight">
                                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                    </span> 
                                </div>
                                <lightning-input required={required} read-only={inputReadOnly} data-id="userinput" label={Label} name="searchText" onchange={searchField} value={selectRecordName} class="leftspace"></lightning-input>

                                <div if:true={iconFlag}>
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right iconheight">
                                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:search" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                    </span> 
                                </div>
                                <div if:true={clearIconFlag}>
                                    <button class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-button slds-button_icon iconheight" onclick={resetData}>
                                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:clear" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Clear</span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Second part display result -->
                            <template if:true={showResult}>
                                <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox" onmouseout={hideRessultDisplay}>
                                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                                        <template for:each={searchRecords} for:item="serecord">
                                            <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" key={serecord.recId}>

                                                <div data-id={serecord.recId} data-name={serecord.recName} onclick={setSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                                                    <span class="slds-media__figure">
                                                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                                                            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span class="slds-media__body">
                                                        <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{serecord.recName}</span>
                                                        <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">{objectName} • {serecord.recName}</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </template>
                                    </ul>
                                </div> 
                            </template>

                            <div if:true={messageFlag}>
                                No result found.
                            </div>
                            <div if:true={LoadingText}>
                                Loading...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

lwcCustomLookup.js

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import getResults from '@salesforce/apex/lwcCustomLookupController.getResults';

export default class LwcCustomLookup extends LightningElement {
    @api objectName = 'Account';
    @api fieldName = 'Name';
    @api selectRecordId = '';
    @api selectRecordName;
    @api Label;
    @api searchRecords = [];
    @api required = false;
    @api iconName = 'action:new_account'
    @api LoadingText = false;
    @track txtclassname = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
    @track messageFlag = false;
    @track iconFlag =  true;
    @track clearIconFlag = false;
    @track inputReadOnly = false;
    @track showResult=true;


    searchField(event) {
        var currentText = event.target.value;
        this.LoadingText = true;

        getResults({ ObjectName: this.objectName, fieldName: this.fieldName, value: currentText  })
        .then(result => {
            this.searchRecords= result;
            this.LoadingText = false;

            this.txtclassname =  result.length > 0 ? 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' : 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
            if(currentText.length > 0 && result.length == 0) {
                this.messageFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.messageFlag = false;
            }

            if(this.selectRecordId != null && this.selectRecordId.length > 0) {
                this.iconFlag = false;
                this.clearIconFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.iconFlag = true;
                this.clearIconFlag = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

   setSelectedRecord(event) {
        var currentText = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
        this.iconFlag = false;
        this.clearIconFlag = true;
        this.selectRecordName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        this.selectRecordId = currentText;
        this.inputReadOnly = true;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selectName}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    resetData(event) {
        this.selectRecordName = "";
        this.selectRecordId = "";
        this.inputReadOnly = false;
        this.iconFlag = true;
        this.clearIconFlag = false;

    }

    hideRessultDisplay() {
        this.showResult = false;
    }
}
```

lwcCustomLookup.css

```
div input[readonly] {
    padding-left: 1.75rem !important;  
}
.slds-input{
    padding-left: 1.75rem !important;
}

.slds-input-has-icon .slds-input__icon {
    top: 56% !important;
}
.slds-icon_small, .slds-icon--small {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

implementing above lookup in below component
helloExpression.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloExpressions" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input
                name="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                value={firstName}
                onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input
                name="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-input>
            <p class="slds-m-top_medium">
                Uppercased Full Name:
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <c-lwc-custom-lookup object-name="Account" field-name="Name" select-record-id={selectRecordId} select-record-name={selectRecordName} icon-name = "action:new_account" onselected={selectedRecords}></c-lwc-custom-lookup> 
            Selected Record: {selectRecordName}
        </div>
        <c-view-source source="lwc/helloExpressions" slot="footer">
            Use JavaScript expressions in a template. Type something in the
            input fields to see the recipe in action.
        </c-view-source>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

helloExpression.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloExpressions extends LightningElement {
    @track firstName = 'First';
    @track lastName = 'Last';
    @track selectRecordId;
    @track selectRecordName;

    handleChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        if (field === 'firstName') {
            this.firstName = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'lastName') {
            this.lastName = event.target.value;
        }
    }

    get uppercasedFullName() {
        let s = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim().toUpperCase();
         //this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value = '';
        return s;
    }

    selectedRecords(event) {
        console.log('selected record--------------');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you indicate, through a screenshot per say where and what you are trying to hide, and if you can simply add a minimal reproduce-able code sample, or only the code part in question that would be relevant? it will help with readability and user engagement =) (quick note, using !important in css is strongly discouraged)

Comment: Added screenshot. I had given all code of my POC so that it will be easier to look into the issue. Anyone can use this code in their personal org and play with it.

Comment: thanks for updating your post =)